# Sending cookie in XHR response but it's not getting stored?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cookies, xmlhttprequest, rails-api

I'm trying to pass an `HttpOnly` cookie with a response from an API I'm writing. The purpose is for the cookie act like a refresh token for the purpose of [silent refresh](https://www.google.com/search?q=silent%20refresh%20definition&oq=silent%20refresh%20def&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j33.3669j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) for a SPA in React.

In my controller method, I've got the following code:

```rb
response.set_cookie(
  :foo,
  {
    value: 'testing',
    expires: 7.days.from_now,
    path: '/api/v1/auth',
    secure: true,
    httponly: true
  }
)
```

I'm making a post request to this action with a `fetch` command like so:

```js
fetch("http://localhost:3001/api/v1/auth", {
  method: 'POST',
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  body: JSON.stringify({
    email: 'aaron@example.com',
    password: '123456',
  })
})
```

Not sure if that matters but I'm wondering if passing cookies in a XHR response doesn't work? However, this seems to be working as you can see in my response I'm getting this:

```
Set-Cookie: foo=testing; path=/api/v1/auth; expires=Sun, 26 Jan 2020 05:15:30 GMT; secure; HttpOnly
```

Also in the `Network` tab under `Cookies` I'm getting this:
[image: Network -> Cookies tab]

However, I'm NOT getting the cookie set under `Application -> Cookies`:
[image: Cookies not showing up]

To clarify, the React app is sitting on `localhost:3000` and the rails backend is listening on `localhost:3001`.

Any ideas?

Comment: Did you try mapping a domain to your localhost? For example `127.0.0.1 test.com` and use it for your testing

Comment: No I didn't. Not sure if CORS is involved with this but in my `cors.rb` file I have this: `origins 'http://localhost:3000'` and like I said port 3000 is where the React app is sitting. Not sure if this is relevant or not.

Comment: CORS is actually not involved in your issue. It seems to be a cookie issue in local, try to set a local domain name I suggested

Comment: Once I tried to store some data in session. It was not showing in browser session as yours but when I tested it through ```byebug``` it was getting stored.

Comment: I didn't think it was but figured I'd mention it just in case. When you're talking about "mapping a domain" are you referring to editing my hosts file?

Comment: Yes, I was. For example "myapp.localhost"

Comment: Isn't `set_cookie` deprecated?

Comment: @Pants I have not seen any deprecation warnings. You might be thinking of a different method?

Comment: @aarona https://apidock.com/rails/ActionDispatch/Response/set_cookie I believe we should be using the `cookie` hash now.

Comment: Ah I see. How would you go about refactoring the code I provided in my question? I believe I tried using the `cookie` method before it only supported one `Set-Cookie` header in the response. I can't remember exactly what it was but I chose `set_cookie` over `cookie` for some reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so it looks like I needed to configure my CORS (in Rails this is your `Rack::CORS` middleware.

I setup my `config/initializers/cors.rb` file like so:

```rb
Rails.application.config.middleware.insert_before 0, Rack::Cors do
  allow do
    origins 'http://localhost:3000'
    resource '*',
      headers: :any,
      methods: [:get, :post, :put, :patch, :delete, :options, :head],
      credentials: true
  end
end
```

and my fetch command should look something like this with `credentials: 'include'` as a parameter:

```js
return fetch(`${endPoint}`, {
    method: 'POST',
    credentials: 'include',
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
      email,
      password,
      password_confirmation: passwordConfirmation
    })
  })
```

Adding `credentials: true` allows cookies to be set by the browser. Apparently, even if you send them, you need `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` in the headers for the browser to do anything with them.

**EDIT:** Recreating this application for learning experience I came across this issue again even after including the `credentials` option. I wasn't seeing the HttpOnly cookie being stored in the browser. Turns out however, that it WAS and does get sent. You can probably test for this in a controller action. Keep this in mind if this solution doesn't 'seem' to work for you!

Comment: Yes, this fixed my issue. I've got HTTP only cookies being stored now and if you use `credentials: 'include'` in your fetch statement they should be sent over with every request (depending on what the path is for the cookie).